# Tkinter: How to enable menubar state by login button

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, controller

I am working on adding menubar to my APP in tkinter. Basically, I would like my menubar to be disabled untill the user loggs in. For now, I have SampleApp class, LoginPage, I created MenuBar as a separate class and few other pages. I would like Menubar to be same in all pages.
I had my few attempts to do this, and ended up on make this work by controller and calling the method created inside MenuBar, which changes the cascade "One" state to normal.
Please excuse, if I'm missing something obvious, I'm kinda novice.
I would be really gratefull for any help. Thank you for your time.

Here's the Traceback:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/DEV/19_03_2018/SampleAPP.py", line 147, in login_btn_clicked
    self.controller.enable_menu()
  File "C:\DEV\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2095, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'enable_menu'
```

And here's my code fragment:

```html
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "SampleAPP")
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="image/sample.ico")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(sticky="nsew")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (LoginPage, PatternCPage, PatternManagerPage, MenuPage):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(LoginPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class MenuBar(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)

        self.create_menu = tk.Menu(tearoff=0)
        self.manager_menu = tk.Menu(tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="One", menu=self.create_menu, state="disabled")
        self.add_cascade(label="Two", menu=self.manager_menu, state="disabled")

        self.create_menu.add_command(label="1")
        self.create_menu.add_command(label="2")
        self.create_menu.add_command(label="3")
        self.manager_menu.add_command(label="1")
        self.manager_menu.add_command(label="2")
        self.manager_menu.add_command(label="3")

    def enable_menu(self):
        self.entryconfig("One", state="normal")


class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        self.label_username = tk.Label(self, text="Username:: ")
        self.label_password = tk.Label(self, text="Password: ")

        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.label_username.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky="e")
        self.label_password.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky="e")
        self.entry_username.grid(row=1, column=5, )
        self.entry_password.grid(row=2, column=5, )
        self.entry_username.bind('<Return>', self.login_btn_clicked)
        self.entry_password.bind('<Return>', self.login_btn_clicked)


        self.logbtn = ttk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=10)
        self.logbtn.bind('<Return>', self.login_btn_clicked)


    def database(self):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='sample', password='sample',
                                  host='samplehost',
                                  database='sampledb')

        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()


    def login_btn_clicked(self, event=None):

        self.database()

        # print("Clicked")
        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()

        # print(username, password)

        if username == "" or password == "":
            tm.showerror("Error", "Empty fields")

        else:
            self.query = ("SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE username=%s AND password=%s")
            self.cursor.execute(self.query, (username, password))
            self.result = self.cursor.fetchall()
            self.cursor.close()

            if len(self.result) > 0:
                tm.showinfo("Access granted", "Logged in!")

                self.controller.show_frame(MenuPage)
                self.controller.enable_menu()

                self.entry_password.delete(0, "end")

            else:
                tm.showerror("Access denied", "Invalid login data")

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made `enable_menu` a method on the `MenuBar`, but you're trying to call it as a method of `SampleApp`.

Comment: Thank you for your response Bryan. How can I call the MenuBar then? Could you be so kind to recall some more code example solution to this issue? Is solution with controller even a way to do this? Or there is other, more effective/simpler way?